# Which reaper ground forces derive from which races?

Tags: mass-effect-3

It's fairly clear that some forms of the reaper ground forces derive from other races - for example *Husks* were once Human and *Banshees* were once Asari, and there are several others that seem fairly obvious.

Others are less so. The *Brute*, for example, immediately makes me think Krogran because of the size and strength, but the head isn't Krogran-like, which doesn't seem to conform to the "looks like a corrupted version of the species" pattern followed else where.

So, **I'd like a *full* list of which of the reaper ground forces have been derived from which races.**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is all explained in the in-game codex. Going from memory:

- Husks: Human
- Cannibals: Batarian (and human, see FAE's comment)
- Brute: mix of Turian and Krogan
- Banshee: Asari
- Ravager: Rachni
- Marauder: Turian
- Harvester: [Harvester](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Harvester) :p

Comment: ill give you the plus one if you know the harvesters.

Comment: Done :p Had to look that one up though ! I can't say I actually remembered harvesters (the non corrupted version) from ME2, to be honest.

Comment: then you definately earned the +1

Comment: @Bethor You see a bunch of harvesters dropping off those fire beetle things from Grunt's Loyalty mission.

Comment: @MrSmooth thanks ! I'll have to replay ME2 one of these days and look out for this :)

Comment: @Bethor you also run into them on a side quest involving a blood pack factory and activating guide beacons

Comment: Cannibals are actually a mix of Batarians *and* humans. Humans comprise their right arms (the one with the gun). They're grafted together in a way that the legs of the human end up merging with the gun. This is explained in greater detail in the ME3 Artbook, and is also clearer to see. In addition, Banshees are created specifically from Asari who were Ardat-Yakshi.

Comment: @FAE nice bit of lore on the batarian/human mix for cannibals ! Added it into my answer :)

Comment: also interesting no salarians were used on any of the reaper forces

Comment: And no Vorchas as well

Comment: @yx. Sur'Kesh was located pretty far from dark space, so it hadn't fallen to the Reapers yet. There aren't really ground troops to make from the Salarians because of this.

Comment: @FAE Not just ardat yakshi, ardat yakshi *OR* those who had the genes to become ardat yakshi. -1 on your comment.

Comment: Vorcha haven't developed FTL travel, which is what the Reapers look for in sentient species. The Vorcha seen are all either a) stragglers who hitched rides from ships that stopped on the Vorcha homeworld, or b) descendants of such stragglers. Not a large amount of Vorcha off of Heshtok to begin with, not a lot of reason to develop and produce Reaper-mutated Vorcha. The Reapers do assault their homeworld, but the Vorcha don't really react to the Reapers war tactics, as one major thing they would do is destroy natural resources to take down a planet.

Comment: Reaper itself is a made from Leviathan

Comment: @Bethor Harvester is in ME2. When you doing Grunt loyalty weapon.

Answer (score -2):

**Spoiler:**

> Seems to me, based on its size and its attacks, that the Brute was created by using the Yahg. The body shape and size are also similar. The only Yahg we know of being off its homeworld was the Shadow Broker. The rest were quarantined to their planet after they killed the Council diplomats that attempted to uplift them like the Salarians did the Krogan before the rebellions. So it is easily assumable that the Reapers attacked and captured all the Yahg on their planet.

Comment: Brutes were formed from (mostly) Turians and some parts Krogan. IIRC the reapers don't harvest any of the non-dominant species (i.e. Yahg) because those will be the ones dominant in the next cycle.